# How to change data location on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I already saw this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/change-mysql-data-directory
but it's not very helpful.

1. What I want: to move my sql data folder to my different place (/media/data)
2. What I did:

   a) `sudo service mysql stop`

   b) `mv /var/lib/mysql/ /media/data/`

   c) `sudo vim /etc/mysql/my/cnf`:

   - section `[mysqld]`:
        `datadir = /var/lib/mysql/` - > `datadir = /media/data/lib/`
   - section `[mysqld_safe]`:
       added:  `datadir = /media/data/lib/`

   d) `sudo vim /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`:

   - added:
       `/media/data/mysql/ r`,
       `/media/data/myql/** rwk`,
   - commented out:
       `#/var/lib/mysql/ r`,
       `#/var/lib/mysql/** rwk`

   e) `sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload`

   f) `sudo service mysql start`
3. What I got:

   a) `tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log`:

   `120215  1:30:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
   /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
   120215  1:30:01 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
   120215  1:30:01  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
   InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
   InnoDB: the directory.
   InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
   InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
   InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.`

   b) Even when sometimes log is clean I cannot connect to server:
      `mysql -u root -p`
      `Enter password:`

      `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run  /mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a shame to admit but the problem was exactly what the error message stated: postgres user had no privileges to access to files even thought all files had correct access rights set. Unfortunately one level up directory hadn't...

Answer (score 1):

I've done that on ubuntu, I don't use apparmor but these are the settings I've changed, all under [mysqld] (I think mysql_safe also uses these settings)

```
datadir = /mysql_data
innodb_data_home_dir = /mysql_data
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /mysql_data
```

I've also put my log files there but that is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1, *.err, *.pid files from your new data directory.
Hope it will work for you!